# How to make weight paint mode use x-ray selecting

Tags: rigging

Basically I want to make all weight painting for a single bone gone on a certain part of the mesh, because moving the arm makes the head mode slightly. I wanted to remove ALL of the paint, so I was wondering if I can do something similar to in edit mode where you go into wire frame mode and box select?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that in weight paint mode:

[image]

- Select the bone
- Activate 'vertex selection masking' (or face selection masking with the button next to the left)
- Now you can select vertices like in edit mode, using <kbd>A</kbd> or box selection or circle selection
- Also you can use (if you need) <kbd>Z</kbd> to select behind/non visible parts (like toggling mesh/solid in edit mode, or like enabling/disabling 'limit selection to visible')

Comment: The selection in Edit Mode determines Weight Paint. If you have 'limit selection to visible' active in Edit Mode before entering Weight Paint, you can box select etc without activating the 'vertex selection mask'.